# Unexplained fuel pump residue that ruined fuel pump

Tags: fuel-system

A couple months back I posted a Question about my sisters fuel pump that suddenly stopped working after she walked Inside, The night before she swore that she had a half tank of gas, To make a long story short I removed the Fuel Pump unit and found this residue, I have no idea what crystal meth looks like. but I would imagine that it looks something like this. Can anyone else Identify what this is that was filled floating in the fuel tank.. almost looks like someone sabotaged her tank

I'm worried because if it is crystal meth then i want to tell local law enforcement, But I don't want them to think. Oh hey druggy we need to lock you up, This is yours

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Wow, that definitely is strange. From what I just read, Meth will dissolve easily in water, but not in acetone. I doubt that would help you any, but thought I'd mention. Whatever the crystals are, it shouldn't be there. I'm doubting it's meth, mainly because that would be quite a quantity to dump into someone's gas tank (read: a waste of a LOT of product). I just don't seem anyone do that. However, it really looks as though someone could have sabotaged her tank. Very well could just be sugar, but those are large crystals for sugar.

Comment: I wanted to find your other post, for background, but can't find it - are you using the same account?

Comment: Do the crystals dissolve in water?

Comment: Were the crystals just inside the fuel pump sender? Or were they in the tank too?

Comment: The crystals don't dissolve in water, they get shiny :) and they were all over inside of the tank @Michael Prokopec

Comment: Someone may have crushed up mothballs to increase the octane of the gas at one point and went overboard, was thinking sugar but that easily dissolves in water. Could actually be drugs as the plastic bag would have dissolved in the gas. The only way to know for sure is to have it tested.

Comment: @Michael Prokopec That's what worries me, I want it tested. But law enforcement would probably look at me like a drug addict, To make a long story short. I found out that the fuel pump actually works when power is supplied to it, water flows like a dream... But didn't inside the tank, So I'm guessing my 0 Psi reading on fuel pressure line was because of this unknown substance clogging the inlet

Comment: You could https://testkitplus.com/ anon... And as for the pressure being zero, yep you bet.

Comment: @Michael Prokopec Seems that those people were crazy lol https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_-kFYsJ_H4 Thanks for the testing equipment, Just what i was looking for